# Global variable getting me null

Tags: java, android

I want to use Global variale in my project so I have simply take a class in which I can set and get any variable dat easily.

**like this::**

```
public class Glob_variable {


        String Path = new String();

        /**********************************************/
        public void setPath(String Path) {
            this.Path = Path;
        }

        public String getPath() {
            return Path;
        }
        /**********************************************/


    }
```

But when I initialize it, I get a null exception.
I have initialized it by creating a object of Glob_variable class.

**like::**

```
Glob_variable g = new Glob_variable();
        g.setPath("asdasd");
```

and when I call in second activity I got null variable when I trace.
I have call like:

```
Glob_variable g = new Glob_variable();
g.getPath();
```

So can you tell me at the which point I have made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because of your are calling get Method from another of your Glob_variable class's instance.

```
Glob_variable g = new Glob_variable();
        g.setPath("asdasd");
        String path = g.getPath();
```

the above code is valid. but if you use below code in another class/activity after using above code in a class, then it is invalid as you have created another instance of Glob_variable in another class/activity.

```
Glob_variable g = new Glob_variable();
String path = g.getPath();
```

Try following single-ton patter in your code,

```
public class Glob_variable 
{
     private Glob_variable GVariableClass;
     private static String Path;
     private Glob_variable()
     {
          GVariableClass = this;
     }

     public static Glob_variable getInstance()
     {
           if ( GVariableClass == null )
           {
                 GVariableClass = new Glob_variable();
           }
           return GVariableClass;
     }

        /**********************************************/
        public void setPath(String Path) {
            this.Path = Path;
        }

        public String getPath() {
            return Path;
        }
        /**********************************************/

    }
```

Comment: may be this issue is raise because i call get method in 2nd activity.with useing `Glob_variable g = new Glob_variable();
g.getPath();` so may be it create new instance at a time....isnt it?

Comment: can you tell me is there any extra process for new string variable `machinename` ? or same as it is

Answer (score 2):

`Glob_variable g = new Glob_variable();` will be create new instance,  use `static` variable or apply `singletone`

**Singletone:**

```
Glob_variable.getInstance().setPath("abc");
String path = Glob_variable.getInstance().getPath(");
```

Comment: i have use static variable earlier but i  am not getting success some time

Comment: it always get same if it is static, use Singleton if static is not preferred

Comment: Static variables should work. If it's not successful, it's probably because of other bugs.

Comment: see, http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html, so only one instance of `Glob_variable` will be used

Answer (score 1):

Well, There are a lot of answers here but I think like me you also come from the VB(or something similar) world(I see all your variables are declared with first letter upper case!).

You have to understand that unlike VB there is no "REAL" global access in Java. When you use 'new' operator a new instance of the class is created and all the values are reassigned as per constructor contract. So scratch off instantiation of a variable for storing global values.

Second option is static variables but I see you are having difficulties in using them as well. Here I have a strong feeling that at times you are using your static variables before you assign them a value. You have to make sure that your setters are always called before your getters. You can even through a custom exception like following

```
public class Glob_variable {


    static String Path = "";

    /**********************************************/
    public static void setPath(String Path) {
        Glob_variable.Path = Path;
    }

    public static String getPath() throws Exception{
        if("".equals(Path)){
           throw new Exception("Variable no inited yet")
        }
        return Path;
    }
    /**********************************************/


}
```

Access your variables by using Glob_variable.getPath() etc. Try following naming convention for Java as well, it will help you in the long run:)

I have found the following link very useful in understanding singltons http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/designpatterns/index.html please read it.

Are the global values constant or do that have to be set on runtime? If they are constant then I would say you create an interface with final variables and use them in your code.